# ASP.NET MVC Views/Controllers management

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, project-management

I'm working on a pretty big project, which have insane ammount of methods in each controller. Same with Views, one folder contains about 150 `.cshtml` files, what makes this hard to explore. I wanted to create separate folder for each part of window, but that changes my routing adress from `./Tavern/Shop` to `/Views/Tavern/Tavern/Shop`. Tavern controller have 3000+ lines of code, and even with (Ctrl+F) its hard to find and edit some functionality.

Any ideas how can i improve this without changing many files in solution?

Comment: _for each part of window_ - maybe you should give us an idea about how the main page is composed of parts.

Comment: I take it a lot of domain logic is within your controller? Maybe you could start by identify it and pulling that out into a seperate layer to make it more manageable. That will make testing etc a lot easier.

Comment: @HenkHolterman One part is a Tavern views: shops, cooking, sleeping etc.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to help without viewing your code but these should be your guidelines:

1. Controllers should be as 'skinny' as possible, all the code should be done in your BL layer. (external lib)
2. Controller should be very specific - i.e. product, contact, home, etc...
3. The routing is done via the controller, and not the location of the view - you can specify on your return View("~/AnyPath/GoesHere/AndTheRouting/IsTheSame.cshtml") (it will be controller/action) (or however you defined it in the routing.config)
4. You can consider working with Areas.